# setup instance group GCE with HTTPS load balancer that allows custom port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm struggling with this setup for 3 days now, most certainly I'm doing something wrong, but from all the docs that I read I have no clue what to is the correct way.

My goal is quite simple. 
I have a docker image in which I have a rest api that is served on 9090 port. 
I would like to have access to it over https, the port doesn't matter, best would be to use 443 (default https port) but this is not mandatory.

What I did so far:
Setup an instance-group with instance-template that uses docker image published on Google Container Registry. This instance-group is behind an HTTPS Load Balancer. 
I have tried a number of different configuration options of the LB to enable access to my instance. 
With instanced created from templates I no longer can setup custom firewall configurations associated with instances, in such way I was able to make a connection to a single VM over HTTP.

Guys, can you help in any way ?

--30.09.2019---------
Configuration Update:

I have engine group setup with named ports: 
http: 9090
https: 9090
[image]

the template is set with both http & https network allowed, but I don't have the possibility to add any rule that would enable 9090 over http or https, or that does not matter?
[image]
[image]

No the Load Balancer:
Frontend:
I have two endpoints: 80 for http and 443 for https. 
The backend uses the named port http(which should point to 9090).

[image]

--- Update 1/10/2019
Firewall rull:
[image]

Health check
[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the following. What are the load balancer frontend and backend configurations? How did you expose the container's port to be accessible outside the container host? There is a lot of information missing from your question. Be as detailed as possible. I would test first with an Unmanaged Instance Group with an existing VM instance. Once you have that working, go to the next steps with a Managed Instance Group. Also, start with HTTP (port 80) then worry about HTTPS (port 443). Normally the Load Balancer handles HTTPS and your backend handles only HTTP.

Comment: updated comment

Comment: 1) Your problem is caused by the health check. The health check is going to port 8080. Do you have a service listening on port 8080? 2) You have two named ports http->9090 and https->9090. Don't create two named ports going to the same destination port. Unless you are using both ports, this is not your problem, but I would delete the https definition. 3) Is your backend (container) supporting HTTP, HTTPS or both? Normally you just need HTTP. 4) Your configuration exposes three container ports (80, 8080, 9090). Which one is your service listening on? Delete the others.

Comment: 5) Once you figure out question #4, enable the correct port in the VPC firewall to allow traffic in on that port.

Comment: yep, I think the health check is the reason, I found out that HC makes the instance-group and lb in `verified state`. 
I have now the backend lb and named port pointing to port 9090 thro http protocol. I have set the template to expose only port 9090. 
Still the only question is if I need to enforce some firewall rull on the vm instance to open the 9090 port or it is ok if I have it in the default netowork ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a firewall rule allow traffic on the port. I mentioned this in item #5.

Comment: how to enforce this rule on the network?
I created a rule with source: 0.0.0.0/0 and allowing all traffic that should be enabled on all instances, but the health check is still not valid.

Comment: Show the details of your health check in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally made it work!
The problem was the firewall rule note being enforced on any of the managed instances. Even if you specify the network and target points this will not enforce the rule to run on the VM instance. You still need to add the network TAG to the instance. Now, with manually managed instances you can do it from the VM settings, if you have a template for the VMs you need to go to Advanced settings > Network > Network Tags when creating your template instance! This is the only way to make the rule applicable on your VM as far as I have read.

For anyone that may have similar issues in the future.
Bellow, you will find the screen. 
[image]

The Http Load balancer is working, probably because of provisioning reasons the https is not, so I will give it 60 minutes still.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Named port](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service?hl=en_US#named_ports) to achieve this.

In the instance group, set port name and port in Port Mapping option.

Then in the load balancer configuration, select a backend then select a named port when prompted. Thats all you need to do.

[image]

Comment: I have both setup, but still the services doesn't let me go throw. I have a firewall rull setup, but I think it does not get enabled on a given instance if I don't set it directly, and I'm not able to do it when instances are managed by the instance-group